# String to Table in R

Tags: r

I have a long string.

```
gs <- "`집합투자 `지정참가 `신탁업자 `일반사무 `총보수 `기타 `총수비 `동종유형 `거래비용 `0.6400 `0.0200 `0.0200 `0.0200 `0.7000 `9.9999 `0.7000 `1.5000 `9.9999"
```

and I marked this string using `, to divide the string easily when I convert this to table.

Then I used read.table function

```
gsdf <- read.table(text = gs, sep="`", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

But the result is not that good, cuz [image: outcome]

as you can see, it has just 0 obs, 19 variables...

What I just want to do is like below picture.

[image: hope]

just 9row by 2col.

How can I convert my string like this?

any function like as.data.frame .. else will be welcomed. please leave for me any reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matrix` instead of `read.table`.

```
gs <- strsplit(gs, '`')[[1]]
gs <- gs[which(gs!='')]
gs <- matrix(gs, ncol = 2)
```